# How do I calculate $(A\times B)^2$ for $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{a,b,c\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, products

> Let $A = \{1,2\}$ and $B = \{a,b,c\}$, find $(A \times B)^2$.

I found $(A \times B) = \{(1,a),(1,b),(1,c),(2,a),(2,b),(2,c)\}$

But how do I find 
$$\{(1,a),(1,b),(1,c),(2,a),(2,b),(2,c)\} \times \{(1,a),(1,b),(1,c),(2,a),(2,b),(2,c)\} $$
?
Is it $\{(1,a,1,a),(1,a,1,b),(1,a,1,c), \ldots\}$ ? 
 
If I am wrong please show me the correct method.

Comment: By $A*B$, do you mean $A\times B$?

Comment: Yeah , A into B.

Comment: I just want to note that $(A\times B)\times (A\times B)$ will give you pairs of pairs instead of 4-tuples (as you suggestd). But more often one denotes $A\times B\times A\times B$ and by this means the exact set you wrote down (it contains 4-tuples). However, mathematicians often blur the distinction between $((a,b),(c,d))$ and $(a,b,c,d)$, so both notations might be considered the same, while technically they are not. It depends on the context and whether a strict dinstinction is necessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are wrong.

The set

$M:=\{(1,a),(1,b),(1,c),(2,a),(2,b),(2,c)\} \times  \{(1,a),(1,b),(1,c),(2,a),(2,b), (2,c)\}$

consists of pairs of pairs.

For example $((1,a), (2,b)) \in M$.

Comment: Why is he wrong?

Comment: @greedoid $(1,a,1,a)\neq ((1,a),(1,a))$.

Comment: Ah yes.........

Answer (score 3):

You will get $36$ elements $$\{((1,a),(1,a)), ((1,a),(1,b)),...,  ((2,c),(2,c))\}$$

Answer (score 2):

For completeness sake, the result is :

$\{\\
 ((1, a), (1, a)),
 ((1, a), (1, b)),
 ((1, a), (1, c)),
 ((1, a), (2, a)),
 ((1, a), (2, b)),
 ((1, a), (2, c)),\\
 ((1, b), (1, a)),
 ((1, b), (1, b)),
 ((1, b), (1, c)),
 ((1, b), (2, a)),
 ((1, b), (2, b)),
 ((1, b), (2, c)),\\
 ((1, c), (1, a)),
 ((1, c), (1, b)),
 ((1, c), (1, c)),
 ((1, c), (2, a)),
 ((1, c), (2, b)),
 ((1, c), (2, c)),\\
 ((2, a), (1, a)),
 ((2, a), (1, b)),
 ((2, a), (1, c)),
 ((2, a), (2, a)),
 ((2, a), (2, b)),
 ((2, a), (2, c)),\\
 ((2, b), (1, a)),
 ((2, b), (1, b)),
 ((2, b), (1, c)),
 ((2, b), (2, a)),
 ((2, b), (2, b)),
 ((2, b), (2, c)),\\
 ((2, c), (1, a)),
 ((2, c), (1, b)),
 ((2, c), (1, c)),
 ((2, c), (2, a)),
 ((2, c), (2, b)),
 ((2, c), (2, c))\\
\}$